# React: problems with ...spreading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to recreate the Redux example from Dan Abramov's course. Spreading the `{...store.getState()}` at App level does not work, Redux is changing the state and React does not re-render.

When I replace line 121 with line 123, the code throws an error.

Full code is here: https://github.com/asaadsaad/redux-react-code/blob/master/13-redux.html

State object:
`{ todos: [{id, text, completed}], visivility: 'ALL' }`

This line works fine:
`<TodoApp todos={store.getState().todos} visibility={store.getState().visivility} />`

This line does not work: 
`<TodoApp {...store.getState()} />`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `combineReducer`'s part:

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
    todos: todos_reducer,
    visivility: visibility_reducer
})
```

Change it to: `visivility -> visibility`

So, why this works with the original one? See:

```
visibility={store.getState().visivility}
```

Here, you are passing `store.getState().visivility` state as `visibility` to your App. Typo fixed here by luck. But when you spread the object `visivility` goes as it is.

Comment: You are welcome. It happens all the time. Sometimes we need a break :) By the way, just try to follow the data like this kind of situation. At first, I did not see the typo. With a couple of `console.log` I see that actually the code can add a `todo` to the store then figure out `visibility` is undefined in the `TodosList` component. The rest was easy.

Comment: Appreciate it.. Thanks.